# How can I spot why the CSS not working in Razor View (model)?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I have build an web application, and I want to delete some record in the database using ASP.NET MVC. But, in the delete Razor View, the CSS is not working, so the page is like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOgvi.png). This is the Delete Page of my application [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eakV7.png). I wonder if there are any solutions for this problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this document describe  `col-sm`, and as i notice the CSS classes that you have been used were marked with red, so maybe the version of bootstrap doesn't contain those classes.

the reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp